# Datatables programmatically apply filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I used the datatables jquery plugin to display a list which is loaded using an ajax call to the server. 
I used the `bFilter` property in order to hide the filter because I want to put the search input inside my sidebar.

```
$(function () {
    var generatedCustomerTable = $('#ItemsTable').DataTable({
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "bSort": true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "/api/Ajax/Test",
            method: "POST",
        },
        columns: [
            { visible: false, data: "id" },
            { orderable: false, data: "name" },
            { orderable: false, data: "value" },
        ],
        bLengthChange: false,       // Hide the page size
        bFilter: false,             // Hide the search box
        ordering: true,
        paging: true,
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        pageLength: 10,
        language: {
            paginate: {
                first: '«',
                previous: '‹',
                next: '›',
                last: '»'
            },
            aria: {
                paginate: {
                    first: 'First',
                    previous: 'Previous',
                    next: 'Next',
                    last: 'Last'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#btnTest").click(function () {
        // I WANT HERE TO SET THE FILTER
        generatedCustomerTable.draw();
    });
});
```

I want programmatically to set the filter text but I have not found a way to do it.

Is there some kind of function which will allow me to set the filter value so that I will be able to call the `.draw()` method in order to refresh the contents of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code , By setting the `bFilter` to  `false` will not only hide the search box but it'll disable also the search function from the dataTable ,

In order to create your own custom search box , you have to enable the `bFilter`, and then either hide the default search control with css (recommended ) by setting :

```
.dataTables_filter {
    display:none;
}
```

, or you make your own table rendering using [sDom](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html) | [other link](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sDom)

See below Snippet :

```js
var dataSet = [
    [ 1, "Name 1","one" ],
    [ 2, "BRimos", "JS" ],
    [ 3, "pitaridis","Data" ],
    [ 4, "Stack", "overflow" ],
    [ 5, "Name 2","two" ],
    [ 6, "Name 3","three" ],
    [ 7, "Name 4","one" ],
    [ 8, "BRimos 2", "JS" ],
    [ 9, "pitaridis 2","Data" ],
    [ 10, "Stack 2", "overflow" ],
    [ 11, "Name 5","two" ],
    [ 12, "Name 6","three" ]
  ];
$(function () {
    var generatedCustomerTable =$('#ItemsTable').DataTable( {
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "bSort": true,
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            {  visible: false,title: "id" },
            {  orderable: false,title: "name" },
            {  orderable: false,title: "value" }
        ],
        bLengthChange: false,       // Hide the page size
        bFilter: true,             // Hide the search box
        ordering: true,
        paging: true,
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        pageLength: 5,
        language: {
            paginate: {
                first: '«',
                previous: '‹',
                next: '›',
                last: '»'
            },
            aria: {
                paginate: {
                    first: 'First',
                    previous: 'Previous',
                    next: 'Next',
                    last: 'Last'
                }
            }
        }
        
    } );

    $("#btnTest").click(function () {
       console.log($("#filter").val(),generatedCustomerTable);
        generatedCustomerTable
        .search($("#filter").val()).draw();
    });
});
```

```css
.dataTables_filter {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<input id="filter" type="text" />
<button id="btnTest">search</button>

<table id="ItemsTable" width="100%"></table>
```